# how to remove element pairs from numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array:

```py
coordinates = np.asarray(list(product(seq, seq))) - fieldSize_va/2.0
```

This coordinates is `numpy.ndarray` type with 1600 elements (pairs). And can be seen as:

```
>>> array([[-4.5, -4.5], [-4.5, -4.26923077], [-4.5 , -4.03846154], ..., [4.5,  4.03846154], [4.5, 4.26923077], [4.5, 4.5]])
```

I have another array:

```py
centralLines = np.asarray([(xa, ya),(xa, yb),(xb, ya),(xb, yb)])
```

which has values as:

```
>>> array([[ 0.11538462,  0.11538462], [ 0.11538462, -0.11538462], [-0.11538462,  0.11538462], [-0.11538462, -0.11538462]])
```

The `coordinates` variable contains all the pairs that are in `centralLines` variable. I want to remove `centralLines` pair elements from `coordinates`. How to do this??

The `coordinates` variable is computed using the following code:

```py
import math
import numpy as np 
from itertools import product
from numpy import linspace,degrees,random

N = 40 * 40

fieldSize_va = 9

seq = linspace(0, fieldSize_va, math.sqrt(N))

coordinates = np.asarray(list(product(seq, seq))) - fieldSize_va/2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

One easy way to solve this would be to sweep the original array and keep the different pairs:

```python
result = np.array([position for position in coordinates if position not in centralLines])
```

However, I must warn you that this solution is not optimized. Perhaps somebody else comes with a faster vectorized solution.

### Sidenote 1

I would recommend you to follow some of the common guidelines of python syntax, namely [PEP8](https://pep8.org/).

### Sidenote 2

Importing numpy just once improves readability of your code!

Repetitive:

```python
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace

seq = linspace(0, fieldSize_va, math.sqrt(N))
```

Better:

```python
import numpy as np

seq = np.linspace(0, fieldSize_va, math.sqrt(N))
```

### Sidenote 3

The square root is already included in numpy, as `np.sqrt`. You can then prescind of importing the `math` module.